# Is it permissible to give someone money for praying?

Tags: halal-haram, salat

Suppose if I had a brother that doesn't pray, and no matter how much you advice he won't pray, but he cares about money so if you give him money he will start praying, and if I kept giving him until he gets used to it and Allah guides him. Is this permissible?

Comment: What if this would only lead him to pray for money?

Comment: I don't know about that, but I guess when he grows up he will become mature and stop asking for money. And what about forcing him to pray? Such as preventing him from doing something that he likes until he prays.

Comment: I knew someone who used to offer their children rewards for not missing any prayers. It created a habit and they kept praying even when the reward was withdrawn when they grew up a little.

Comment: UmH, yes but is giving them money actually halal? I also read that in a book but the author didn't refer to a Hadith or anything.

Answer (score 1):

May Allah forgive me if I am wrong, but I think that it is permissible. It is permitted to punish kids above ten years old in order to motivate them to pray. If punishing is permitted then positive incentives should also be permitted as it achieves the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's permissible. You can ask him to pray with concentration and attention and slow.
Slowly he'll start praying without money.